# USB OTG w/ Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: usb, dns, otg

I'm following [Simple guide for setting up OTG modes on the Raspberry Pi Zero, the fast way!](https://gist.github.com/gbaman/975e2db164b3ca2b51ae11e45e8fd40a)

What I've done;

1. flashed latest (`2017-04-10`) Raspbian image onto SD card,
2. added `dtoverlay=dwc2` on new line to `config.txt`
3. created blank `ssh` file (without any extension) on `./boot` partition,
4. modified `cmdline.txt` file, by adding `modules-load=dwc2,g_ether` right after `rootwait`,
5. booted Raspberry Pi Zero, waited for 90 seconds and tried to `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` using `ssh` openssh client with `Linux` and `PuTTY` on Windows (Pi connected to PC using USB cable).

There was *NO* other changes made to SD card, other then what I mentioned above.

I'm able to ssh in from `MacOS` & `Windows`, but not from `Linux`:

```
$ ssh -v pi@raspberrypi.local
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/alexus/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi.local: Name or service not known
$
```

What am I missing?

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
$ systemctl status avahi-daemon.service | grep Active
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-04-25 12:04:30 EDT; 2h 14min ago
$ grep ^hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:      files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
$ avahi-browse --all --domain=local --verbose --terminate | grep -vE '(eno1|docker0|virbr0)'
Server version: avahi 0.6.31; Host name: X.local
E Ifce Prot Name                                          Type                 Domain
: Cache exhausted
: All for now
$
```

Please advise.

---

*** UPDATE ***

`NSSWITCH.CONF(5)`:

```
$ grep ^hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:      files mdns_minimal dns mdns myhostname
$
```

`avahi-daemon.conf(5)`:

```
$ grep ^use-ipv /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf 
use-ipv4=yes
use-ipv6=yes
$
```

`use-ipv6=yes` is disabled by default. I un-comment that line followed by restart of `avahi-daemon.socket` & `avahi-daemon.service`, I now *sometimes* able to see following:

```
$ avahi-browse --all --domain=local | grep -vE '(docker0|virbr0|eno1)'
+ enp0s20u8 IPv6 raspberrypi [XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX]               Workstation          local
- enp0s20u8 IPv6 raspberrypi [XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX]               Workstation          local
$
```

per output above, `raspberrypi` entry comes and goes

`avahi-daemon`@`Linux`:

```
May  5 10:42:10 wcmisdlin02 avahi-daemon[8336]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s20u7.IPv6 with address fe80::150b:ff04:b4e9:692e.
May  5 10:42:10 wcmisdlin02 avahi-daemon[8336]: New relevant interface enp0s20u7.IPv6 for mDNS.
May  5 10:42:10 wcmisdlin02 avahi-daemon[8336]: Registering new address record for fe80::150b:ff04:b4e9:692e on enp0s20u7.*.
May  5 10:42:54 wcmisdlin02 avahi-daemon[8336]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::150b:ff04:b4e9:692e on enp0s20u7.
May  5 10:42:54 wcmisdlin02 avahi-daemon[8336]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s20u7.IPv6 with address fe80::150b:ff04:b4e9:692e.
May  5 10:42:54 wcmisdlin02 avahi-daemon[8336]: Interface enp0s20u7.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
```

`- enp0s20u7 IPv6 raspberrypi [XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX]               Workstation          local`:

```
$ ssh -v pi@raspberrypi.local
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/alexus/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi.local: Name or service not known
$
```

`+ enp0s20u7 IPv6 raspberrypi [XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX]               Workstation          local`:

```
$ ssh -v pi@raspberrypi.local
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/alexus/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to raspberrypi.local [fe80::e0e0:f91:8e3:73b3] port 22.
debug1: connect to address fe80::e0e0:f91:8e3:73b3 port 22: Invalid argument
ssh: connect to host raspberrypi.local port 22: Invalid argument
$ ssh -6 pi@fe80::e0e0:f91:8e3:73b3%enp0s20u7 uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.50+ #970 Mon Feb 20 19:12:50 GMT 2017 armv6l GNU/Linux
$
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? advise on what?

Comment: How is the pI connected to the network or PC? What  SSH software are you using? What if any error message are you getting? Did you wait long enough for the Pi to boot fully? How did you create the SSH file? Are you sure it does not have a file extension? Do not answer the above questions in the comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: the command needed to create the ssh file is touch /boot/ssh (which is not what you have above)

Comment: @SteveRobillard I'd presume `/PATH/` indicates the card is mounted in another system.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I created `ssh` inside of `/boot` (relative to SD card)

Comment: Can either one of @SteveRobillard and/or jacobm001 help me understand what is unclear about my question and how I can improve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: My comments pertain to a previous version of the question. In the latest version, the previous versions left out any info that would help us answer the question. you can't SSH because the computer you are using can not identify the PI on the network using raspberrypi.local. Have you changed the hostname? Do you have bonjour networking support installed (itunes on a PC will do this).

Comment: @Jacobm001 pinging you since you weren't mentioned properly above.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I updated my question right away after your comment and later on, I incorporated all updates into my initial question for better reading experience, after that you and Jacobm001 placed my question on hold, if I'm missing anything I'd gladly to add to help troubleshoot my question. I'm using vanilla Raspbian (no changes, other the one I mentioned in my question). I mainly use Linux so no iTunes there, however when I did test it with my Windows PC, iTunes is installed there.

Comment: My vote was recorded when I initially read your question. You can vote to reopen. However, you just added additional info in the comments that belong in your question.

Comment: @SteveRobillard, question isn't closed, so nothing to vote on) and added all relevant information to my question as well) big thanks for helping me improve my question)

Comment: I agreed with Steve's assessment, that at the time I closed it there simply wasn't enough information to answer the question.

Comment: Since there have clearly been significant edits since then I will reopen the question.

Answer (score 3):

I understand this question is quite old, and perhaps resolved in some way other than posted.  However, I've posted an answer to a similar question on the Unix and Linux StackExchange.

The short answer is that the GNU/Linux host Pc's Ethernet port needs to be setup with a network bridge through Network Manager's commandline tool `nmcli`.  And then the Pi's OTG Network interface needs to be added to that bridge.  Your DHCP server should then give your Pi an IP address through the GNU/Linux host PC bridged ethernet port.

Here's the longer answer:

[How to setup Networking via Network Manager's nmcli for a Raspberry Pi connected to a host PC via the USB port running in OTG mode.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401950/256823)

Hopefully this helps, if you still need help.

Answer (score 0):

When using RNDIS to connect to a Linux host machine, the biggest pitfall (compared to the procedure with Mac/Windows) may be that you need to switch the connection method under IPv4 Settings to **Link-Local Only** instead of Automatic.

There's some mention of that in [this other question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66836/raspberry-pi-zero-and-ubuntu-ethernet-over-usb) and [here too](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/73523/connect-pi-zero-via-usb-rndis-gadget-to-ubuntu-17-04).

Otherwise, this works out of the box for me connecting a Raspbian 8 device with `g_ether` to an Ubuntu 16.04 desktop.

Well, it works for connecting one time. Another pitfall specific to Linux is that NetworkManager creates a new connection entry each time.

Could you confirm if you've already attempted configuring Link-Local Only? If the problem persists, please specify your host Linux distro (apparently it's something older with OpenSSH 6) to help narrow down. There is probably a lot else that could go wrong depending on interplay between Avahi, NetworkManager, and all things USB/ethernet.

Answer (score -1):

To me the "Could not resolve host name raspberrypi.local" would indicate that there is not any ip address connected to that hostname. You could try to use the ip address. If the ip address is static, that would be easy. If it changes, you could try a ping script to locate it. See question/answer  [Unable to resolve IP address for RPi connected through ethernet](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66275/unable-to-resolve-ip-address-for-rpi-connected-through-ethernet/66310#66310).

```
pi@RPi3:~ $ for x in $(seq 2 20); do ping -rc1 -W1 192.168.0.$x | grep 'from'; done
```

Comment: kind of defeats zeroconf altogether, not to mention it works for some platforms such as MacOS and Windows, just not Linux.

Comment: You are right. I'm not up on zeroconf, but if you just want to ssh from Linux system, you could try using ipv6, see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/raspberry-pi/5701/getting-started-with-raspberry-pi/24491/login-with-ipv6#t=201704291153226221397.

Comment: I believe you're missing the whole point of `zeroconf`, as in order for me to get ipv6, I _still_ have to hook it up to hdmi with keyboard and then login to get ip address. I'd like to understand what I can do on my Linux so I can connect to rpi without connecting it to anything other then USB OTG.

Comment: Is the 'avahi-daemon' running (`ps -ef | grep avahi`) on the Linux box? From Linux, will it `ping -c1 raspberrypi.local` and `ping -c1 raspberrypi`, how about `ping -rc1 -I eth0 raspberrypi.local`? Does `host raspberrypi.local` gives IP address (very bad! See #11 at http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/internal-network-is-not-resolving-hosts-and-ping-redirected-to-198-105-244-228-a-4175528190/). I am just learning about `zeroconf`.

Comment: as I stated in my original question `avahi-daemon.service` *IS* `active (running)`, I'm unable to `ping` or `host` against `raspberrypi.local`.

Comment: I would believe the problem lies in the Linux box as it will accept the IP address. Windows and MAC can use `raspberrypi.local`. The only other thing that I have found is the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file needs `hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns` or mdns before dns.

Comment: I updated my question with `^hosts:` line from `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

Comment: Will the Linux system ssh to it self using hostname.local?  How are the four systems connected, router, hub, wire, wifi? Single network? Are IPs dhcp, static or system default? Would `tcpdump` help to isolate the problem? I have not used it, may be someone else could commit on it?

Comment: I can ssh to my own hostname.local, my outside connection is really irrelevant here, as I'm troubleshooting connection between my computer in which raspberry-pi plugged-in via USB and with `tcpdump`, I see `DHCP Discover`, multicast and etc...