# Raspberry Pi Zero and Ubuntu: ethernet over USB

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet

I'm trying to connect to my Raspberry Pi Zero over USB. The steps I followed are:

1. Added `dtoverlay=dwc2` to `config.txt` at `boot` partition
2. Added `modules-load=dwc2,g_ether` after `rootwait` to `cmdline.txt` at `boot` partition
3. Connected my rpi to my computer through the micro-usb data port.

This results in `network manager` from my computer creating a new wired connection, which implies a new network interface with an IPv6 assigned ip.

`avahi-daemon` is up and running, but something is failing. My `wired connection` disconnects and reconnects all the time.

`avahi-browse` returns something like:

```
+ enp0s26u1u1 IPv6 raspberrypi [12:81:40:9a:91:66]               Workstation          local
- enp0s26u1u1 IPv6 raspberrypi [12:81:40:9a:91:66]               Workstation          local
+ enp0s26u1u1 IPv6 raspberrypi [12:81:40:9a:91:66]               Workstation          local
- enp0s26u1u1 IPv6 raspberrypi [12:81:40:9a:91:66]               Workstation          local
+ enp0s26u1u1 IPv6 raspberrypi [12:81:40:9a:91:66]               Workstation          local
- enp0s26u1u1 IPv6 raspberrypi [12:81:40:9a:91:66]               Workstation          local
+ enp0s26u1u1 IPv6 raspberrypi [12:81:40:9a:91:66]               Workstation          local
- enp0s26u1u1 IPv6 raspberrypi [12:81:40:9a:91:66]               Workstation          local
+ enp0s26u1u1 IPv6 raspberrypi [12:81:40:9a:91:66]               Workstation          local
- enp0s26u1u1 IPv6 raspberrypi [12:81:40:9a:91:66]               Workstation          local
+ enp0s26u1u1 IPv6 raspberrypi [12:81:40:9a:91:66]               Workstation          local
```

A quick fix I found for the disconnections is to go to `IPv6 Settings` from my wired connection and select `Link-Local Only` as method. Later, to connect to my pi, I ping the whole network to retrieve its IPv6 address `$ ping6 -I enp0s26u1u1 ff02::1`. Finally I connect through ssh to the IP I just discovered `$ ssh -6 pi@fe80::fa1a:6601:e3a1:4a31%enp0s26u1u1`.

Inside the raspberry pi, running `$ ip a s` shows that the rpi has an IPv4 address! So know that I know the network, I can assign an IPv4 address to my workstation.

The problem is that I have to repeat, all this steps each time I connect/disconnect the USB from the rpi.

I was wondering if someone knows how to avoid repeating all the process, because obviously something is failing.

Thanks!

Comment: Does either machine (Ubuntu or Pi) show a reason for the disconnect?

I too had a lot of difficulty getting Ethernet connectivity between my Pi Zero and a Ubuntu laptop.  I was able to get the Pi zero to automatically assign an Automatic Private IP address (APIPA-169.254.0.0/16) address by putting `iface usb0 inet dhcp` into `/etc/network/interfaces` on the Pi 0 and then un-commenting the `timeout` in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`.  However, I had to configure a static IP address on the network interface created in Ubuntu for the Pi `enp0s29u1u2` to get a reliable connection.

Answer (score 6):

Open the `Edit Connections` dialog, edit your `wired connection x` on your Ubuntu machine (16.04LTS here) and in the tab IPv4-settings set Method to `Link-Local Only`

That will make a reliable connection, and you can ssh afterward

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
```

The first time I could easily connect wit ssh, but the pi zero itself had no internet access. I disconnected and connected again and afterwards the pi had internet access so I could `apt update` the pi, without changing anything.