# Pi don't connect to PC via USB (Etcher built two partision in SD Card)

Tags: usb, sd-card

I need to connect my raspberry Zero  to my PC via USB (with my Linux LMDE ), Si i found [this instruction](https://www.instructables.com/id/Connect-to-a-Raspberry-Pi-Zero-W-Via-USB-No-Mini-H/).

Firstly i downloaded the [Raspbian Stretch with desktop](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_latest) version for my SD card and i use etcher to write Raspbian on my SD card. but when it's  done i have two partition in my SD card as seen blown:

[image: SD card two partition]

So  i do this instructions:

```
Open the "config.txt" file with Notepad++

Scroll all the way down to the bottom.

Type "dtoverlay=dwc2" in the last line and then add an extra line after that.

Save and close the file.

Open "cmdline.txt" file with Notepad++

Find a section after "rootwait"

Paste "modules-load=dwc2,g_ether" in said section.

Save and close the file.

Create a new file called "ssh"

Eject the MicroSD Card and place it on your Raspberry Pi
```

finally when I connect my raspberry zero to my pc via USB cable i write this code:

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
```

I got this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi.local: Name or service not known
```

my raspberry is working and it's LED is on (Green).

**UPADATE:**

According to comments,I have installed `ssh` again with this code `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` but again that problem exist.

I run `lsusb` with and without pi conected to USB port and i get this answer:

```
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 0525:a4a2 Netchip Technology, Inc. Linux-USB Ethernet/RNDIS Gadget
```

Shown blow:
[image: lsusb]

when i run `ifconfig usb0` I get:

```
usb0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

but when i write `ifconfig -a` i get (based of comparing result on with & without pi connected to USB):

```
enp0s20f0u1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether be:32:12:f4:45:07  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

My solution:

I do [this as solution](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/73523/connect-pi-zero-via-usb-rndis-gadget-to-ubuntu-17-04) :

[image: solution]
Thanks a lot.

Comment: "To be able to connect to your Raspberry Pi using Putty in Windows, you need to have Bonjour installed, otherwise you'll get an error"

Comment: Hello, looks like you're on Linux (based on the screenshot anyway) so try `avahi-browser` or some such from the package manager. Does `lsusb` or `dmesg` show the enumerated Pi ethernet gadget? Does the ethernet gadget need a DHCP server to connect?

Comment: You also seem to expect SSH to work without enabling it first.

Comment: This previous answer might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/73924/93934