# SOLVED Raspberry Pi Zero v1.3 Gadget Mode

Tags: linux, networking, usb, debian

I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/ethernet-gadget) and a number of others to get my Pi Zero to run in gadget mode. That particular article mentioned in passing that the Pi might be misidentified by Windows as a COM device. After some digging, I found an Acer RNDIS driver and now the Pi works with Windows.

However, I can't get the Pi to work with my Linux machine (my daily machine with all my files) and I can't find any information about why. Avahi is installed and known to be working because I use it to access my file server quite regularly.

The XFCE network manager shows a new USB network when the Pi is connected (Netchip Linux-USB Gadget) but fails to connect to it - getting hung up on 'Acquiring IP address' until it eventually aborts.

Setting up manual addressing is not an option in this context, I need my Pi to be relatively plug-and-play, able to move between PCs with a minimum of hassle or setup.

Any advice or insight you could offer would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After days of this question getting batted between different sites of this network I've already found an answer:

[Connect Pi-Zero via USB RNDIS Gadget to Ubuntu 17.04](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/73523/connect-pi-zero-via-usb-rndis-gadget-to-ubuntu-17-04?rq=1)

For anyone who's curious, in the Network Manager, the IPv4 needs to be set to link-local and IPv6 set to ignored. This lets you connect without issue.